# How to Get Winget package with API

Tags: c#, winget

A few days ago, Microsoft introduced Rest API for `Winget`. I want to use API that Microsoft uses to get packages on `Winget` in my C# application. But there is no documentation for this. Both projects are open source ([winget-cli](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli) and [winget-cli-restsource](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource))
Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with C++ code.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same question. I want to use c# to find the latest version of a specific package in Winget.

Answer (score 0):

Additional documentation and a PowerShell script to aid in deployment are in progress (as of today 10/7/2021).

https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource/pull/61

Comment: any pratical example on how to use these API from (for instance) a shell script using `cURL` on Linux ?

Comment: Open API files are located at https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli-restsource/tree/main/documentation. That should help get you started with the various endpoints.

Comment: The yaml files have not even http in them, and their format is not really documented? Unclear how to use that